# python: program hanging! (print issue maybe?)

Tags: python, list, primes

So, I'm quite nooby at python. I decided to make a program that makes prime numbers. I know there's probably a function built in that does this but I decided to do it myself.

```
number = 1
numlist = list()
for x in range (0, 1000):
    numlist.append("")
    print "Created list entry " + str(x)
while True:
    number = number + 1
    if number % 2 != 0:
        numscrollerA = 1
        numscrollerB = 1
        while numscrollerA <= number:
            if float(number) / float(numscrollerA) == float(int(number)):
                numlist[numscrollerA] = "true"
            if float(number) / float(numscrollerA) != float(int(number)):
                numlist[numscrollerA] = "false"
            numscrollerA = numscrollerA + 1
        while numscrollerB <= number:
            if numscrollerB != 1 and numscroller != number and numlist[numscrollerB] == "true":
                primestatus = "false"
            else:
                primestatus = "true"
        if primestatus == "true":
            print number
```

I get "Created list entry *x*" 1000 times as I should. Then the program just hangs.

Comment: You have `while True:` loop - this is an infinite loop, you need to break out of it somewhere

Comment: I know, my method was that when the list ran out of spaces it created an exception. Not the most elegant, but this is only a learning experience.

Comment: so just wait few days... when program 'hangs' it means that it is running an infinite loop. If it is what you expected... just be patient ;o)

Comment: @m.wasowski I'm at least expecting it prints a prime. It doesn't seem to be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while numscrollerB <= number:
        if numscrollerB != 1 and numscroller != number and numlist[numscrollerB] == "true":
            primestatus = "false"
        else:
            primestatus = "true"
```

You don't increase numscrollerB in this loop, so it runs infinitedly. Anyway, You should rather use 'for loop':

```
for numscrollerB in range(1, number+1):
    pass  # do something
```

Comment: Now it prints odd numbers, including composite numbers.

Comment: yes, but that's another one of problems with your code. My advice: start with something simpler, test it and build-up incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very unpythonic. Typical of a newcomer experienced in a different style of coding.
Your list is uneccessary.
In python you could create the list like this

```
def check_even(val):
    #this contains your logic
    return val % 2 == 0

evenslist = [check_even(i) for i in xrange(1, 1001)]

print numlist
```

Comment: that's a definition for an even number—not a [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Comment: yes, I was just showing how to be more pythonic. The OP can fill in the logic of the function to return true for primes.